# How To Capture All Templates And Static Files Before They're Sent To Client

Tags: python, django

In Django >= 1.11, how would I go about capturing the rendered HTML templates and statically served files to make programmatic changes to them before they are sent to the client?

I had made a custom "render" function, but soon realized that this only works on rendered templates and not static files.

I would like to capture all files served over the server, not just rendered ones.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Static files are not served by django, outside the development server.

Comment: I am trying to make changes to the files so that they contain slightly different information every time that they are served. Obfuscation of sorts but not as extreme  @4140tm

Comment: Well then you need to actually make your static files go through Django. In other words, make them not static any more.